# git, how to change file between branches without commit/tracking

Tags: git, branch

My setup is like this:

- master branch
- dev branch

My master branch is connected to github for my deployment workflow. I have a file (wp-config.php) which is not tracked (settings in live system are different), but I want to differentiate the (local) database for master and dev.

When I track & commit the file change in dev branch (not in master), it gets deleted in master branch (not really in the branch as it's not tracked, but it disappears on my hard drive when check-out master).

When I track & stash the changes in master and dev, I can't execute the stash in dev branch because git is telling me that the file already exists.

Do you have a suggestion how I can solve this?

Comment: If this file isn't tracked anyway, can't you simply add logic to it to use the correct settings based on which branch you're on, or something like this?

Comment: Do you mean by adding code in my php file? But how should the environment know the branch in which it's executed?
/edit in fact I thought I could add "a little bit of logic" here by stashing the changes in each branch and then execute it when I am checking out the branch. I think this would be the right way, but it's not working or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Per process you could, if you want, execute `git branch` or similar and learn which branch is currently being checked out in your folder. You could cache this value in the process memory or cache so that you don't need to execute this each time. Again, this relies on the file being 100% local and not supposed to go into the repository.

Comment: You should probably commit a *template* of your configuration file to your repository, and stop running your code directly from your Git working directory. You should have an installation process that *copies* code to a real deployment directory, where you can keep the appropriate configuration files. (If the configuration files don't contain any sensitive information like login credentials, you can keep them all in Git, like `wp-config-prod.php` and `wp-config-dev.php`, and copy the appropriate one during installation.)

Comment: If your `wp-config.php` will not be overwritten by WP, you could just add it to `.gitignore` and add PHP code in your `wp-config.php` that checks the file `.git/HEAD` for the content `ref: refs/heads/master` to detect whether you're on `master` or `dev`. And then sets the configuration accordingly there.

Comment: Thanks for all your input! 
With your help, it gave me the idea (simple but working): wp-config.php is now tracked & committed in all branches, but excluded in my deployment process from github to my server. It's that easy sometimes :)